# Margin-Top not working for span element?

Tags: css, margin, html

Can someone tell me what I coded wrong? Everything is working, the only thing is that there is no margin at the top.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="contact_us"> <!-- BEGIN CONTACT US -->
  <span class="first_title">Contact</span>
  <span class="second_title">Us</span>
  <p class="content">For any questions whatsoever please contact us through the following e-mail address:</p></br></br>
  <p class="e-mail">info@e-mail.com</p></br></br></br></br>
  <p class="read_more"><a href="underconstruction.html">Read More</a></p>
</div> <!-- END CONTACT US -->
```

**CSS**:

```css
span.first_title {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #221461;
}

span.second_title {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #b8b2d4;
}
```

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Unlike `div`, `p` <sup>1</sup> which are [Block Level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) elements which can take up `margin` on all sides,`span`<sup>2</sup> cannot as it's an [Inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) element which takes up margins horizontally only.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The
>   'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while
>   the other margin properties only set their respective side. These
>   properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have
>   any effect on non-replaced inline elements.

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9VJS/) (Vertical `margin` not applied as `span` is an `inline` element)

Solution? Make your `span` element, `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9VJS/1/)

Would suggest you to use `display: inline-block;` as it will be `inline` as well as `block`. Making it `block` only will result in your element to render [*on another line*](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9VJS/2/), as `block` level elements take `100%` of horizontal space on the page, unless they are made `inline-block` or they are `floated` to `left` or `right`.

---

<sup>1. [Block Level Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) - MDN Source</sup>

<sup>2. [Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements) - MDN Resource</sup>

Comment: the best explanation for the beginners. Thanks million @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 100):

Looks like you missed some options, try to add:

```css
position: relative;
top: 25px;
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answers the question, but is a good solution to the problem!

Answer (score 17):

`span` element is `display:inline;` by default you need to make it `inline-block` or `block`

Change your CSS to be like this

```css
span.first_title {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:24px;
    color: #221461;
    /*The change*/
    display:inline-block; /*or display:block;*/
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`span` is an inline element that doesn't support vertical margins. Put the margin on the outer `div` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`<span>`tag doesn't accept  `margin`, `padding` you need to add some css style and make your `<span>` tag as `block` or `inline-block` in order to use `margin`, `padding` for `<span>` tags, but the best way to use is `div` tag.

```
span{ display:inline-block or block;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Always remember one thing: we can not apply margin vertically to inline elements. If you want to apply vertical margins then change its display type to `block` or `inline-block`

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```