# Make span and input equally sized

Tags: css, input, html

In the following snippet I want `<span>1</span>` to have the same width, as `<input type="text" size="1" value="1" />`
Same for second `span` and second `input`. And so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<div>
    <span>1</span>    
    <span>2</span>    
    <span>3</span>    
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" size="1" value="1" />
    <input type="text" size="1" value="2" />
    <input type="text" size="1" value="3" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I accomplish this with css?

UPD: Sorry, I did not make it clear, that it must be 2 rows. Row of `span`s and row of `input`s

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Hy2HC/

Comment: Give your elements width and make them display as blocks? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to retain the `span` elements `inline` behavior, but `inline`<sup>1</sup> elements don't take `width`, so assign `display: inline-block;` to your `span` elements

```
div span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

div input[type=text] {
    width: 25px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua9R5/)

<sup>1. [Inline Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700999/1542290)</sup>

Note: As you might be aware, `inline-block` retains white space between the elements, to get rid of that, either call `font-size: 0;` on the parent element, or consider `floating` your elements to the `left`, and you don't have to use `size` attribute anymore, consider assigning `width` to the elements using CSS instead.

---

Also make sure you normalize your CSS for cross browser consistency.

Comment: You'll also need to account for the border of the span, which is counted as part of the input.  
You can either add 2 pixels to the input width (or subtract from the span width), or a cleaner solution might be to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your elements.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the size of one on the inputs and add a class.
(Just in case you dont know, `1 em = the current font-size`)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>
    .one {
        width: 1em;
    }
    .two {
        width: 1em;
    }
    .three {
        width: 1em;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <span class="one">1</span>    
    <span class="two">2</span>    
    <span class="three">3</span>    
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="one" value="1" />
    <input type="text" class="two" value="2" />
    <input type="text" class="three" value="3" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm22x/) :

```
span, input {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:222px;
    height: 33px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    float:left
}
```

BUT, by forcing the input in a border-box layout, you will have to deal with some other situations....

Somehow, i feel ashamed trying to help you without seeing first what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to remain your span's, you could use something like this:

```
#wrapper
{
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
}

span, input
{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bS3pX/)**

However, your layout is so close to a table layout. So why not use the `<table>` element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>3</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="text" size="1" value="1" /> 
        </td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" size="1" value="2" /> 
        </td>
         <td>
           <input type="text" size="1" value="3" /> 
        </td>        
    </tr>       
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bS3pX/1/)**