# use span to create a separator

Tags: html, css

I create an empty span with css `border: 1px solid #333` but didn't see any working separator. I think there must be something inside the span? how to create a border with empty tag? a `hr` tag is too ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give it a size, and display it as a block. Try this.

```
span.separator {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Km9kw/)**

Comment: didn't see your post, while I was posting... gave yours an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

`hr` tag is not ugly if you use `border: 0;` and than use `border-top: 1px solid #000;`, the 3d style of `hr` is just applied by browser, you can alter it the way I suggested.

```
hr {
   border: 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 10px auto; /* For vertical spacing */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/75tgY/)

I would suggest you to use `<hr />` as semantic goes, it will give a meaning to your page and will also save you few characters in the source.

---

Secondly about the `span` tag, it's an `inline` tag, to span it `100%` you need to make it `display: block;`.

```
span.separator {
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   display: block;
   margin: 10px auto; /* For vertical spacing */
}
```

For more information on `inline` `span` you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700999/1542290).

Answer (score 0):

A span is not a block element, in order to get what you want, you would have to give it a height and set it as display:block or inline-block.
If you want the border to be only on one side you can use border-right or border-left;

```
test <span style="display:inline-block;height:13px;border:1px solid black;"></span> test
```

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Cm5fK/