# override computed css value

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to customize the height of my ahref element in my website. I have set a class value, and the class value in my CSS file looks like this :

```
.CockpitArrowLink {
    height: 70px !important;
    font-size : 13px;
    min-height:70px !important;
}
```

I want my height to be set at 70px, but it always shows as 16px. I am thinking that the font size is having an effect on the size. If i look at my style tab in chrome, I see no mention of these 16px hoever plenty of mentions of the 70px.

[image]

However if I look at the computed tab in Chrome, i see that the height of my ahref is auto, and if I hover of the blue box, i see that it is 16px.

[image]

How do I override this value?

Comment: 16px is probably your default font size in `body {  }`

Comment: Not related to the question really, but - awesome MSPaint-Fu! :)

Comment: @UweB its snipping tool, and it don't let you write text :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes nope, not the problem

Comment: Have you tried changing the `a` to `display: inline-block;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to customize the height of my **a href element** in my
>   website

So `<a>` elements are *inline* by default, just like `span` or say `img` and hence your `height` property won't work on *inline* elements, even if you apply margins, they will only work horizontally and not vertically, so inorder to make it work, use `inline-block` or `block`<sup>[1]</sup>

*(<sup>[1]</sup> If you want the element to take all available horizontal space)*

```
.CockpitArrowLink {
    height: 70px;
    font-size : 13px;
    display: inline-block; /* Add this */

    /* Use vertical-align if required */
    vertical-align: middle; /* or top as a value */
}
```

For more information you can [read my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element) on `span` element which is also an `inline` element by default.

---

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height) :

> *Applies to* : all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge to set the height on the inline element you'll need to add display: inline-block; See below:

```
.CockpitArrowLink { 
    height: 70px;
    font-size : 13px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the link's css show 70px height, but only heights 16px.

Anchors are by default inline elements, and inline elements only use the height of the elements they contain. In this case the text. If you want to set their height you have to **change the type of display to block or inline-block**. Then you will be able to set heights, paddings, etc... that otherwise won't affect the element.