# Margin-top/Margin-bottom not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm working on a bigger web project and the following snippets are just extracts of two larger html/css documents.

But the problem remains:
I'm not able to insert  `margin-top/bottom` for my textboxes.

I want to achieve 2 things:

- Adding more rows with text boxes if needed - with a defined space between these rows.
- Use the same defined space after an auto break of a single row. This snippet is embedded many auto generated pages. So I don't know how many of these white boxes will be displayed. I want to achieve a fancier behavior after resizing the browser window too.

**HTML/CSS - Minimal (not) working example:**

```css
body {
  font-family: Gill Sans, Gill Sans MT, Calibri, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
span.bigger {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /*not working*/
  margin-top: 225px;
  margin-bottom: 225px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
</div>
No margin
```

---

**What I want to achieve:**
[image]

Comment: spans are inline element, and they don't have top and bottom margins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Margin-Top not working for span element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `span` is an inline element, and `margin-top/bottom` doesn't work in inline elements, so make it a  [inline-level block container element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display).

> **inline-block**
>
> This value causes an element to generate an **inline-level block container**. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

```css
body {
  font-family: Gill Sans, Gill Sans MT, Calibri, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
span.bigger {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
  <span class="bigger">Text-Text-Text</span>
</div>
No margin
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you, it works (obviously)!