# CSS for navigation :hover pushing content on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I've been working on our site using a WordPress theme that I've tweaked a bit, and noticed that the drop-down nav in Safari for :hover is displaying too low and pushing down other content on the page. Seems to be related to padding, but I can't figure it out.

I saw other posts on this sort of thing, but nothing quite like my scenario. Ideas?

http://dev2.bingdesign.com/ - the nav above the slider.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think margin of span element doesn't work on safari.

So if you add the margin top to span element on safari, please change `display: block` into `display: inline-block`.

Please check this link: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I see what is being suggested, I just am not having an easy time finding it. Will keep digging.

Comment: No Problem. Good Luck.

Comment: It seems I have narrowed down my issue to this: li a span { padding: 0 !important; } but there is still a block for :hover that appears below the links and shoves the slider down in Safari. I'm having issue with finding the right element to make inline-block. Can you offer some more breadcrumbs to the answer for me?

Comment: Hi I can help you, but I can access your site again now.

Comment: Thank you! Just let me know when you can see it.

Comment: I think I finally found the issue!! The top nav was working without the shift, but the second nav was not. Between the negative margin for the slider, adding a left float, and mimicking the top nav, I think I should be good. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome!! Good luck!