# why all margin in spans do not work? do they accept only one margin or what?

Tags: html, css, margin

In my code, I have styled all span tags and margin-left works fine in all tags but margin-top is not working at all. It happens all the time with me, so I thought to ask if I have any misconception of span tag. Please help!

```
<div id="header">
    <span id="logospan" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 8px;"> <img src="logo.png" width="70px" height="70px"> </span>
    <span id="homespan" style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;"> <img src="1.png"    width="40px" height="40px"> </span> 
    <span id=""         style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;"> HOME </span>
</div>
```

Comment: spans are inline. You should read up on the css `display` atrribute so that you understand it, and what the default `display` is for certain HTML elements. `div`'s are display block btw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: Be sure to search before posting you question, there are a number of related posts that have the answer to the question you just asked.

Answer (score 7):

`<span>` is an inline element so top and bottom margins do not apply.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting

Answer (score 3):

> so I thought to ask if I have any misconception of span tag

You do; they're inline elements, meaning Y-axis margins are effectless on them. You can keep their inline behaviour but give them margin by setting their `display` property to `inline-block`, i.e.

```
.someClass span { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since span tags are inline, not block elements. They can only take margin left and right, not top and bottom.

See this related post,

[Margin-Top not working for span element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element)

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` in both the elements. **it works**

```html
<div id="header">
    <span id="logospan" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 8px;vertical-align:top;"> <img src="logo.png" width="70px" height="70px"> </span>
    <span id="homespan" style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;vertical-align:top;"> <img src="1.png"    width="40px" height="40px"> </span> 
    <span id=""         style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;vertical-align:top;"> HOME </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Chrome/PC). The top margin is not honoured.

Comment: it works. i did even check in firefox and chrome. the home link gets top and images are being at bottom

Comment: Who says the images should be at the bottom? Image 1 has a margin-top of 8px. Change it to 80px and you'll see its not being honoured.

Comment: Why in the name of the universe, would you do that? :D

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin margins apply to all elements, except elements with `table` display types other than `table-caption`, `table` and `inline-table`. However, vertical margins will not have any effect inline elements.

In your case a `span` in inline (rather than block level) and thus cannot be given vertical margins. However, simply changing them to `inline-block` will rectify this. You may also want to consider the vertical alignment as adding a top margin to something that's baseline aligned may not be much use.

```css
span {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <span id="logospan" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 8px;"> <img src="logo.png" width="70px" height="70px"> </span>
    <span id="homespan" style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;"> <img src="1.png"    width="40px" height="40px"> </span> 
    <span id=""         style="margin-left: 150px;margin-top: 0px;"> HOME </span>
</div>
```

P.S I suspect that you are using these top margins in order to vertically align these elements. In which case `vertical-align:middle` may be a better method.