# Margin not appearing

Tags: html, css

I wish my margin was also on the top of the text just like it is on the sides and the bottom

```css
.text_line {
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin: 60px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<Section>
  <span class="text_line">Isso é um teste 1</span>
  <span class="text_line">Isso é um teste 2</span>
</Section>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

---

[edit]

actually i didnt know it was happening because a span element is linear. It took me quite a while to find it out

Comment: if you add `display: inline-block;` to `.text_line` is that the output you were expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike div or p tags which are Block Level elements which can take up margin on all sides, span cannot as it's an Inline element which takes up margins horizontally only.

See: [Margin-Top not working for span element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700985/margin-top-not-working-for-span-element)